# PHP imagecreatefromjpeg() works from command line, fails from HTTP

Tags: php, gd

I am trying to use a PHP script to scale all JPG images in a directory using GD image functions.  The script works when I execute it from the command line, but not when it's called via HTTP.  Logging indicates it fails on the call to `imagecreatefromjpeg()`.  GD seems to be installed and properly configured, as the call to `getimagesize()` succeeds.  It seems to be a valid image file, for the same reason.

Any help greatly appreciated.

Relevant code (some code deleted for readability):

```
while (false !== ($entry = readdir($fh))) {
    $pathinfo = pathinfo($entry);
    if ('jpg' === strtolower($pathinfo[ 'extension' ])) {
        $log->info(sprintf('Processing file "%s"', $entry));
        $srcName = implode(DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR, [$config[ 'stageDir' ], $pathinfo[ 'basename' ]]);
        if ( ! file_exists($srcName)) {
            $log->warning(sprintf('File "%s" not found', $srcName));
            continue;
        }

        if ( false === ( $info = getimagesize($srcName))) {
            $log->warning('This file is not a valid image');
        }
        var_dump($info);
        echo imagecreatefromjpeg($srcName) . "\n";

        if (false === ($srcImg = imagecreatefromjpeg($srcName))) {
            $log->warning(sprintf('Cannot read image file "%s"', $srcName));
            continue;
        }
    }
}
```

Command line output:

```
C:\Apache24\htdocs\kiosk\public>php convert.php
C:\Apache24\htdocs\kiosk\public\convert.php:75:
array(7) {
  [0] =>
  int(3072)
  [1] =>
  int(2304)
  [2] =>
  int(2)
  [3] =>
  string(26) "width="3072" height="2304""
  'bits' =>
  int(8)
  'channels' =>
  int(3)
  'mime' =>
  string(10) "image/jpeg"
}
Resource id #26
```

Logging file when executed via HTTP:

```
[2020-01-01 07:22:50] gallery.INFO: Processing file "IMG_2748.JPG" [] []
[2020-01-01 07:22:50] gallery.WARNING: Cannot read image file "../staging\IMG_2748.JPG" [] []
```

Windows 10, Apache 2.4, PHP 7.2
Here is the GD info from php -i:

```
gd

GD Support => enabled
GD Version => bundled (2.1.0 compatible)
FreeType Support => enabled
FreeType Linkage => with freetype
FreeType Version => 2.8.1
GIF Read Support => enabled
GIF Create Support => enabled
JPEG Support => enabled
libJPEG Version => 9 compatible
PNG Support => enabled
libPNG Version => 1.6.34
WBMP Support => enabled
XPM Support => enabled
libXpm Version => 30512
XBM Support => enabled
WebP Support => enabled

Directive => Local Value => Master Value
gd.jpeg_ignore_warning => 1 => 1
```

Comment: use a phpinfo() to check ypur extensions in http mode. most likely your cli is using a different php.ini file than apache + php mod

Comment: Its not an issue with the extensions. Its most likely an issue with the paths - try runnng those relative paths through realpath() and check they point where you think.

Comment: @cfv1000 php -i (command line) and phpinfo() (HTTP script) seem to show the same ini file: path to C:\Windows and loaded config file c:\php-7.2\php.ini

Comment: @symcbean I changed the code to `$srcName = realpath(implode(DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR, [$config[ 'stageDir' ], $pathinfo[ 'basename' ]]))` per your suggestion.  Same results as before.

Comment: @symcbean Yes.  Here are the log entries: (I do not know how to add line feeds to SO comments.  Sorry.)  `[2020-01-01 14:38:29] gallery.INFO: Processing file "IMG_2748.JPG" [] []
[2020-01-01 14:38:29] gallery.INFO: C:\Apache24\htdocs\kiosk\staging\IMG_2748.JPG [] []
[2020-01-01 14:38:29] gallery.WARNING: Cannot read image file "C:\Apache24\htdocs\kiosk\staging\IMG_2748.JPG" [] []`  The variable `$srcName` is defined once, using `realpath(),`  and used for all further functions

Comment: Are you asking me to check if these paths are correct?

Comment: @flapjack What is the output of `var_dump($srcName, file_exists($srcName), is_file($srcName), is_readable($srcName), imagecreatefromjpeg($srcName));` before the `if()` statement, where you try to read the image file?

Comment: @symcbean No, I provided the log output in case you had doubts that I had actually verified what you suggested and wanted to verify it for yourself.

Comment: @Progman `C:\Apache24\htdocs\kiosk\classes\ImgConverter.php:124:string C:\Apache24\htdocs\kiosk\staging\Photo0905.jpg' (length=46)
C:\Apache24\htdocs\kiosk\classes\ImgConverter.php:124:boolean true
C:\Apache24\htdocs\kiosk\classes\ImgConverter.php:124:boolean true
C:\Apache24\htdocs\kiosk\classes\ImgConverter.php:124:boolean true
C:\Apache24\htdocs\kiosk\classes\ImgConverter.php:124:boolean false`

Answer (score 0):

Found [a solution](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imagecreatefromjpeg.php#120569) in the comments section of the function documentation on the PHP.net site.  It does not explain why it works from the command line but not from an HTTP request, nor does it explain why the function call fails.  It does, however, provide a work-around:

```
$image = @ImageCreateFromJpeg($image_name);
if (!$image)
{
    $image= imagecreatefromstring(file_get_contents($image_name));
}
```